# (Lack of) alignment on the migrated tab on the tools page

Tags: feature-request, migration, 10k-tools, design

When scrolling down on [the Migrated tab on the Tools page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=migrated&daterange=today) the arrows and the icons of the sites jump left and right. This is very "annoying" when scrolling.

[image: jumping arrows]

Perhaps the texts and the icons can be placed in a fixed width container so that the arrows are always on the same spot? And maybe the icons be centered in the fixed width container? To make the elements less jumpy when scrolling.

Comment: unfortunately only moderators can view this page.

Comment: Nopez not only moderators, but 10k user. The screenshot I've added should give you an idea.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that the `.question-info` class has a `text-align: center` on it. Since each site is a different length, centering them causes slight variations in placement. I don't know how important that property is in that class, or where else that class is used. A general search through a few page sources for "question-info" doesn't return any results. Anyways, aligning the boxes to the left would fix the issue.

[image: Aligned left instead of centered]